# Can't create a list from a set

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong:

```
(Pdb) aaa = set(list1).intersection(list2)
(Pdb) list(aaa)
*** Error in argument: '(aaa)'
(Pdb) type(aaa)
<type 'set'>
```

This code should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Its's working exactly fine on my machine python 2.7

Comment: I did what you say in python 3 without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` is a command in `pdb` to list source lines. Use `p list(aaa)`.

Comment: At last I've found "whereami" for pdb.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the debugger. While `pdg` tries to accept much Python code, some Python code resembles PDB commands so much that it is interpreted as a PDB command rather than Python code. Such as lines starting with `list`, which is a PDB command that displays source code. Use `p list(aaa)`. `p` is the PDB command for "evaluate the following Python expression and print its result".